# Query regarding displaying data on BaseAdapter

Tags: android

I am displaying a list of items using the BaseAdapter.  The data which I am displaying for the BaseAdapter is ArrayList which is properly displayed. 
When the data is empty , a blank screen is displayed which is perfect. 
I wanted to show a single text at the middle of the screen which is "No data found" . If I am adding the text "No data found" to the ArrayList when the data is not there , then every list element will display the "No data found" which is not right , since I want a single text on the whole screen.

How can I display the "No data found"  at the centre of the screen? I dont want to use any background image to display the data.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ListView's [setEmptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29).

Also, you can add a view with id "@android:id/empty" that will be shown instead of the ListView when the list is empty. Make sure you are using a ListActivity.